# Irregular barplot spacing using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have tried to create a barplot using ggplot2, but one of the categorical variables is occupying the space where another should be. There is data missing for 'Orbit' and I assume this is why 'Alex' has been over spaced. Below is the code I already have

```
ggplot(ObsData, aes(factor(Vacc_Stage), Sparring, fill = Giraffe))+
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, geom="bar", position = "dodge")+
  labs(title="Sparring", y="Mean Frequency of Behaviour Performed Per 15-Minute Observation", x="Vaccination Stage")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Alex" = "grey", "Orbit" = "black"))
```

[image]

Is there anyway to change this so bar widths are consistent?

[Data Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPEeP.png)

Comment: please specifiy the dataframe `ObsData` with `dput()` or `dput(head(ObsData))` (if it is long)

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, group = gear, fill = gear)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "bar", 
               # position = "dodge")  # equivalent
               position = position_dodge(preserve = "total"))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg, group = gear, fill = gear)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "bar", 
               position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]